# Unable to access python array from php

Tags: php, python, xampp

I have two code snippets:-

1) get_pos_tags.py

```
import sys
import json
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

def getPOSTags(sentence=sys.argv[1]):
    sentence_s=str(sentence)
    word_token=word_tokenize(sentence_s)
    print word_token
    word_POS_tags=pos_tag(word_token)

if __name__=='__main__':
    getPOSTags()
```

2)test.php

```
<?php
$sentence="I became the king of rome";
echo("python get_pos_tags.py "."'".$sentence."'",$output);
var_dump($output);
```

When I run test.php on xampp, I receive the output of xampp as null whereas I should get the output in the form of python List.Can anyone help what's wrong with this code? I'm using MAC OS X El Capitan and PHP7.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much PHP, but you may want to look into piping the output from your python script into your php script using sys.stdout